# Getting started jqueryUI

Tags: jquery-ui

I am just trying to get the most basic thing going here and am being completely stopped.  I am trying to follow the examples but for some reason even getting a basic example working is thwarting me.  Here I am just trying to get the JQueryUI select menu to work.  The demo page for this works fine for me but when I try to use my own page it does nothing (no error either).

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <title>Demo Page for jQuery UI selectmenu</title>

    <link type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(function(){

            $('#testselect').selectmenu({style:'dropdown'});
        });
    </script> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <select id="testselect"> 
        <option value="test1">Op 1</option> 
        <option value="test2">Op 2</option> 
        <option value="test3">Op 3</option> 
    </select> 
</body> 
</html>
```

It looks like I am getting a "object doesn't support this method" error on the selectmenu line but I don't know why this would not be available since based on the demos it seems like this should work given the script links are there and pointing to a valid location.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>It's not `$('#testselect').selectmenu();` but `$('#testselect').selectable();`, see [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/) (if you're talking about that).</strike>

**Update:**

The SelectMenu widget, as stated in the [documentation page](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138056/Selectmenu) you linked, it's still under development. It doesn't exists yet, so you can't use it (or you can try to merge it into current jQueryUI at your own risk).

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this effect:
http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138056/Selectmenu

Comment: @Mark: Disregard my previous comment. I missed a fundamental thing: that's a page regarding a core jQueryUI widget *under development*. That means that wideget does not exists yet.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense then, I missed the in development part.  I am supposed to be making a dropdown that looks like this and it looked like this much have been where they got it from for the comp.  Thank you for the help, back to the drawing board I guess.